# Apex callout event type in wave event monitoring app

Tags: event, einstein-analytics

Is there a way to pull report for apex callouts in event monitoring wave app. I see there are pre built datasets for other events like URI, API etc but I don't see anything for ApexCallout event type.

How can I monitor ApexCallout event_type records in wave event monitoring app?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [`EventLogFile`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_eventlogfile.htm) documentation the very first supported value for the `EventType` field is `Apex Callout`:

> **Apex Callout**
>   Apex Callout events contain details about callouts (external requests) during Apex code execution.

The exported `LogFile` csv has these fields:

- `CLIENT_IP`
- `CPU_TIME`
- `EVENT_TYPE`
- `LOGIN_KEY`
- `METHOD`
- `ORGANIZATION_ID`
- `REQUEST_ID`
- `REQUEST_SIZE`
- `RESPONSE_SIZE`
- `RUN_TIME`
- `SESSION_KEY`
- `SUCCESS`
- `TIME`
- `TIMESTAMP`
- `TIMESTAMP_DERIVED`
- `TYPE`
- `URI`
- `URI_ID_DERIVED`
- `URL`
- `USER_ID`
- `USER_ID_DERIVED`

Comment: I am not sure if we should mention this but this is a paid-feature and not available for all orgs. https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=Event-Log-Files&type=1

Comment: I can get the file from REST API or the heroku app for apex callout event type, but I am looking for that event type in the wave monitoring app.

Answer (score 0):

Until now, there is only pre-built dashboards and dataset for Apex Execution Event Type.
If you want to use another Event type, you could populate a custom object with pre-processed data through an Apex job, or get it with External API and insert it at a custom object (to use a Dataflow) or an external database (to use Data Sync and Connection functionality)
PD: I've posted an Idea for that:
https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000ED7fQAG